# Can a storage cap / limit be established to protect a Mac with low storage from iCloud download / local caching of data?

Tags: macos, icloud, storage, automation

I have a mac mini of 1 tb and a macbook air of 256gb, so my air is almost not usable because it keeps filling up leaving 1-2gb of free space. I can't even run my softwares to work correctly so i'm stuck to working from home and don't want to reduce the amount of data I store in iCloud from my Mac mini.

Is there a script, or a known way through terminal on macos to put a cap to the local space used for icloud documents sync and storage?

Comment: The OS *should* throw out downloaded items as necessary.  I don't believe it would download so much from iCloud as to only leave you 1gb on the internal drive.

Comment: I agree with Marc - why can't you put more of the "local" storage from the 256 Mac into the cloud so that the software can juggle what you have space for locally?

Comment: It doesn't work like that thus why i am asking here.... I already have it both set-up on the same desktop and documents through both devices. No local only storage on any device. Icloud will forcely try and download all files on the cloud so if you have a smaller hard drive on one of your devices, as soon as it's synced and even if optimize storage is on, it will create an of infinite loop where it tries to download all documents.  There is no option to cap this limit as of now.